# Unable to display error message for cakephp3 bootstrap-ui

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bootstrap-ui

- [x] bug
- BootstrapUI Version: v0.5.0
- Bootstrap Framework Version: v3.3.6
- jQuery: 3.0.0-rc1
- Platform and Target: Google Chrome, Apache

#### What you did

App\View
    namespace App\View;

```
use Cake\View\View;
use BootstrapUI\View\UIViewTrait;

class AppView extends View
{
    use UIViewTrait;

    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        //render the initializeUI method from the UIViewTrait
        $this->initializeUI();
        $this->layout('default');
    }
}
```

controller/create function

```
$student = $this->Students->newEntity($data['Students']);
if (!$this->Students->save($student)) {
    $isOkay = false;
    debug($student);
}
```

create.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['align' => [
   'sm' => [
       'left' => 4,
       'middle' => 8,
       'right' => 12
   ],
   'md' => [
       'left' => 2,
       'middle' => 6,
       'right' => 4
   ]

], 'id' => 'myform']); ?>

<fieldset id="page-1">
   <legend>Student Profile</legend>

   <?php
       echo $this->Form->input('Students.name', [
           'label' => 'Full name'
       ]);
   ?>
</fieldset>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

StudentsTable.php

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
  $validator
    - > integer('id') - > allowEmpty('id', 'create');

  $validator
    - > notEmpty('name', 'Username must input.');
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

I expect I will getting error block beside the field.

#### Actual Behavior

The error message is missing from page, but I can found it in controller.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$student` variable from controller to view `create.ctp`. Also you need to pass `$student` variable into the form you want to display errors. In you case it will be:

`$this->Form->create($student, ['align' => [...`

**Note:** in both case `$student` variable should be an entity of `StudentsTable.php`.